# How do you level a dragon beyond level 20?

Tags: dragonvale

How do I get my level 20 dragons beyond that point
? I hear it is possible to get them to level 26? Is that just for Elder dragons or all of them and how do you do it? I am level 125 and have all the dragons, but I can’t get them any higher it seems.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Dragonvale FAQ](https://support.backflipstudios.com/hc/en-us/articles/234571508-DragonVale-World-General-FAQ), the maximum level a dragon can reach is 20.

Comment: the primary dragons can be levelled to 21, they then become elder dragons.